# can't connect to remote mysql database via navicat

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, navicat

I have a mysql database on an unmanaged rackspace cloud server. I can connect to phpmyadmin with no issues. I checked if port 3306 is listening and it is. `/etc/mysql/my.conf` shows `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`.

When I use navicat to connect via ssh, it says `SSH tunnel: Invalid username or password!` I've reset my passwords and restarted mysql and the server just to make sure but I still can't connect. What can I try next to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please connect to MySQL and run

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

What does this output ???

- [`USER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL
- [`CURRENT_USER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

If the output of these two functions do not match, you will need to create a user that matches the `USER()` or `CURRENT_USER()`.

If they are both `root@localhost`, please run

```
SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user;
```

Now, visible compare if all root users have the same password.

Also, please check the contents of `/etc/hosts` on the server.

This not fully an answer, but I hope this helps !!!

Comment: they all have the same passwords

Comment: I am not a Rackspace person, but should check for Rackspace's way of managing security groups for IP Access to its server.

Comment: I had to add a new user with specific ip address to get it working...why wouldn't `%` work? for host?

Comment: It's probably trapped by Rackspace since using % as host allows for remote DB Connections from anywhere. In general, that's not secure.

Comment: I'll try to check with them. Thanks for your help!